# How to calculate False Positive Rate (FPR) if sum of False Positve and True Negative is Zero?

Tags: machine-learning, roc, false-positive

I am working on performance measuring and trying to draw a ROC curve, however to draw ROC curve i need TPR and FPR.

As we know,

> False Positive Rate (FPR) = FP / (FP + TN)

I have got values of TN and FP both equal to 0, so how can i calculate FPR for this case and put in ROC curve?

Comment: This is off-topic, rather on-topic in stats.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all

> False Positive Rate (FPR) = FP / (FP + TN)

thus

> I have got values of TP and FP both equal to 0

is not a problem, as TP is not used in this equation. The only problem would be for FP + TN to be 0, but this is impossible since FP + TN = Negatives (all samples with negative label, no matter how you classify them). Consequently the only case then FPR is undefined is **if your dataset does not have negative samples**, and then there is no point in binary classification either way.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my question TP supposed to be TN, thank you

Comment: this means that your dataset does not contain **any** negative samples, thus it is not a valid binary labeled dataset. You either compute TN / FP incorrectly, or your data is invalid.

Comment: Can please clear my confusion about detecting True Negative in this frame? @lejlot http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39645367/how-to-classify-true-negative-from-a-video